# How to save and load to preferences Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am making program, which copy files from directory to other directories in **Windows Forms C#**. But I tried save and load directory path to *Preferences > Settings* and its not working. Copying, deleting its already good, only this saving and loading doesnt work. I want do this: user can in textbox write path to source and target directory and save it. That when user want copy files, he dont need write path again and again because program save path in this preferences.

Form:

[image]

There are source path and target path for directory. Then "Save values" should save this paths as string. And "Save backup" copy files. **Text_box1 is textbox next to "Source path" and text_box2 is "Target path"**

Here is code:

```
namespace AutoSave
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string sourcePath;
        string targetPath;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(targetPath);
        if (dir.Exists)
        {
            DeleteDirectory(targetPath);
            CopyFiles();
        }
        else
        {
            CopyFiles();
        }
    }

    private void CopyFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            var dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir1.GetFiles())
            {
                string targetFilePath = Path.Combine(targetPath, file.Name);
                file.CopyTo(targetFilePath);
            }
            label2.Text = "Save is successful";
        }
        catch
        {
            label2.Text = "Something is wrong";
        }
    }

    public static void DeleteDirectory(string target_dir)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(target_dir);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(target_dir);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            DeleteDirectory(dir);
        }

        Directory.Delete(target_dir, false);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    //SAVE PATHS
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sourcePath = textBox1.Text;
        targetPath = textBox2.Text;

        Properties.Settings.Default.SourcePath = targetPath;
        Properties.Settings.Default.TargetPath = sourcePath;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Have I bad code or what I did bad please? Have you some tips? In advance I am sorry for my English i tried my best :D Thanks for help.

Comment: The best way to make questions is not showing all your application and telling "_this part does not work_" but making a [mcve]. In your question your code but your `button2_Click` is unnecesary.

Comment: Hi, please, be more specific about these points: (1) do a screenshot of the Settings.settings grid (2) when you say it doesn't work, how do you know it doesn't work? What does the program do? Do you get a warning, an error message, en exception?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Program runs good, there are not error messages. Just this saving doesnt work. In Settings grid I have 2 strings, scope is set to "User". I didnt build it yet. But in editor it doesnt work. Values from this two textboxes are not save in Settings. I want to do something like: you write this 2 paths you save it. You can quit app and when you saved it. App will remember your paths, then you dont need write it again and again. Now I can just copy files from source path to target path thats it.

Comment: @Cleptus in buttton2_Click I am actually trying save this path from textboxes to Settings :D

Comment: Yeah, but you lack information on if they did persist/got saved or not. Checking [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) they say "_User settings are saved in a file within a subfolder of the user’s local hidden application data folder_"

Comment: Oh, then when I want save data and keep it saved, how I can do this? Save it as txt file or json and read it on app start?

Comment: Yes, you have to write << textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TargetPath >> etc. at the begginning (in the constructor, Form_Load,... ) so that your app starts well.

Comment: By the way, your 2 strings sourcePath and targetPath are redundant. But if you wish, you can write in two steps: << targetPath = Properties.Settings.Default.TargetPath >> and then << textBox1.Text = targetPath >>, same thing with sourcePath.

Comment: @Fredy I got it. Thank you for your tips :)